# Use an array of pointers to retrieve objects Parse API

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, pointers, parse-platform

I'm using Parse API with swift. In `_User` class, I have a column called `posts` which contains an array of pointers. This is stored by calling

```
PFUser.currentUser().setObject([PFObject], forKey: "posts")
```

The pointers in the array are just `PFObject`s of the posts that the user has uploaded. The posts contain some `String` values like `title` and `comments`, as well as an array of `images`.

Since `PFUser` is cached locally, is it possible to retrieve the images by calling

```
currentUser().objectForKey("posts")
```

or do I have to make a query call?

I'm currently getting the `objectId`s from the array of pointers, and calling `query.findObjects()` with `whereKey caintainedIn: [objectId]` to retrieve all posts info. But I think if my posts class gets very large, this is very inefficient because every `objectId` in posts class is being compared to my `objectId`s.

Is there a way to efficiently retrieve all objects from an array of pointers?

Comment: You should set up a relation in Parse instead, because as you note, an array can very quickly become inefficient, and Parse recommends that arrays be of size less than 100 elements

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from @pbush25 a relationship may suit you better.

For a small array of pointers you don't need to do a find request, but for the `User` class you do need to `fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:` (just once, before you try to use it) to get the custom columns of data as getting the `currentUser()` only includes the standard columns of data.

Comment: If I add a relation column in each post object, I would still need to use whereKey equalTo: currentUser() right? How is that different from using an array of pointers and also make a query with whereKey containedIn:[objectId]?

Comment: How can I get all objects that the pointers point to in the array? I'm just trying to avoid making a query with whereKey equalTo: or containedIn:, because these functions will compare all objects in a class to my query correct? And I believe this will slow down if my class contains very large amount of objects. I was first trying to get all objects using their objectIds but I don't think there is a function that allows you to retrieve an array of objects unless you use whereKey functions, which will slow down the query as I stated above.

Comment: You query the relation, no parameters